# Keep same position on element in relation to other element regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a design with one large svg and three divs with text, absolutely positioned with CSS. I need the divs to keep their position in relation to the svg regardless of what the screen size is. That is, I want the text blocks to always stay aligned with the "branches". How do I do that?

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/jennie-andersson/pen/YzpLaYW)

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}

.box-1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 33%;
}

.box-2 {
  top: 650px;
  left: 52%;
}
.box-3 {
  top: 1210px;
  left: 36%;
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg 
    width="185" 
    height="1668" 
    fill="none"
    aria-hidden="true"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path
      d="M39.5 1665c-19.95 2.85 41.323-1.26 64.771-2.89 3.419-.23 5.362-4.82 4.327-8.09-14.809-46.76 97.758-206.14 69.902-341.52-11.147-54.17-45.229-110.52-81-155.5-29.944-37.66-66.9-57.98-80.5-113-4.3-17.39-7.5-61 0-101 7.48-39.898 75.652-305.146 75.999-306.495l.004-.017c.299-1.343 25.703-115.554 35.497-210.988 17.272-168.304-21.4-281.623-76.296-423C95.73 126.455 138.393 276.328 117 463.5c-15.937 139.438-77.961 332.565-86.5 368-18.986 129-54 199 5.5 271.5s115.046 146.4 126 209.5c27.348 157.54-98 349-122.5 352.5z" 
      fill="#EAECF0" 
      stroke="#E9EBEF" 
      strokeWidth="4" 
      strokeLinejoin="round"
    />
    <path 
      d="M82 1252.94c29.227 11.7 82.878 10.06 82.878 49.65l-3.649 7.89C155 1269.5 95.918 1268.2 82 1252.94zM53.699 105.984c19.085 10.888 35.112 33.394 49.806 52.952v-15.085c-5.59-14.883-38.466-35.764-49.806-42.914-4.816-3.037-14.605-3.284 0 5.047zM78.5 715c-10.345 8.248-21.099 16.711-23.44 30.98l2.968 8.728C64 730.258 97.5 707 111.234 699.579 100.824 702.026 87.1 708.144 78.5 715z" 
      fill="#E9EBEF"
    />
  </svg>
  <div  class="box-1 left">
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3 left">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to insert the text inside the SVG as <text> nodes? You should also add a viewBox to the SVG element

Comment: I don't think that is an option. I don't know the amount of text beforehand, it all comes from a CMS. But the text will most likely span over multiple lines so I need to set a width on the text container.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is positioned towards the left edge of the surrounding div in percent. If you wan to svg to behave the same, you have to position it as well.

I added css that does that. The main rationale is to treat the elements that are supposed to behave the same the same way.

### Update:

You can use padding on the `.text-box` elements to influence the position of the text. Again, the box is positioned in the exact way as the svg (by percentage of the viewport width). To fine tune the position on in relation to the svg canvas, use something that adds a fixed offset to the percentage wise positioning.

(The `.inner` elements are only there to display the padding with a background. You can remove them when you're doing this.)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-box,
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text-box {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.text-box .inner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1);
}

.box-1 {
  top: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.box-2 {
  top: 650px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.box-3 {
  top: 1210px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <svg width="185" height="1668" fill="none" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path
            d="M39.5 1665c-19.95 2.85 41.323-1.26 64.771-2.89 3.419-.23 5.362-4.82 4.327-8.09-14.809-46.76 97.758-206.14 69.902-341.52-11.147-54.17-45.229-110.52-81-155.5-29.944-37.66-66.9-57.98-80.5-113-4.3-17.39-7.5-61 0-101 7.48-39.898 75.652-305.146 75.999-306.495l.004-.017c.299-1.343 25.703-115.554 35.497-210.988 17.272-168.304-21.4-281.623-76.296-423C95.73 126.455 138.393 276.328 117 463.5c-15.937 139.438-77.961 332.565-86.5 368-18.986 129-54 199 5.5 271.5s115.046 146.4 126 209.5c27.348 157.54-98 349-122.5 352.5z" 
            fill="#EAECF0" 
            stroke="#E9EBEF" 
            strokeWidth="4" 
            strokeLinejoin="round"
          />
          <path d="M82 1252.94c29.227 11.7 82.878 10.06 82.878 49.65l-3.649 7.89C155 1269.5 95.918 1268.2 82 1252.94zM53.699 105.984c19.085 10.888 35.112 33.394 49.806 52.952v-15.085c-5.59-14.883-38.466-35.764-49.806-42.914-4.816-3.037-14.605-3.284 0 5.047zM78.5 715c-10.345 8.248-21.099 16.711-23.44 30.98l2.968 8.728C64 730.258 97.5 707 111.234 699.579 100.824 702.026 87.1 708.144 78.5 715z" 
            fill="#E9EBEF"
          />
        </svg>
  <div class="text-box box-1 left">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>20px padding to the left</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-box box-2">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>40px padding to the left</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-box box-3 left">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>60px padding to the left</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it your way, but the text-boxes need different percentage to be placed to the left or right of the "tree trunk". It doesn't work when I resize the browser window.

Comment: Got ya, I edited the snippet to add more fine tuned positioning that doesn't interfere with the 'link' between text boxes and svg